# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/<local_path>/venv/pyvenv.cfg'

Tags: python, django, macos, cron

I am running a Django application with a few cron tasks. Whenever I run `python manage.py crontab add` to register the cron tasks, I get a "mail" in the Terminal showing the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 609, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 592, in main
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 510, in venv
    with open(virtual_conf, encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/<local_path>/venv/pyvenv.cfg'
```

I am running on macOS Catalina, python 3.7.3 in a virtual environment venv.

I have tried giving full disk permission to bash, crontab, terminal, xcode and pycharm.

I have also tried installing python versions 3.7.8 and 3.8.3

#### Partially solved

I disabled System Integrity Protection using `csrutil disable` in Recovery Mode and the cron ran successfully. However, I do not see it as full solution.

#### Final solution

I dockerized the app and ran it as a docker container.

Comment: The same problem has not been solved -.-

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem and after a few searching i found a error with cron permissions.

This is how i solved:

- Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy - Privacy -> Full Disk
  Access
- Click on the + icon to add an item

  *If the lock appears locked, click on him to unlock with your user password*
- Press Command + Shift + G to open a dialog
- Type /usr/sbin/cron and press Enter
- Search and select the cron file and click Open

Okay, now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the PermissionError is that the Python virtual environment is placed in the user directory.
If you put the virtual environment in a system directory, such as /opt, there will be no problem. See example below:

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/myvenv
$ cd /opt/myvenv
$ sudo python3 -m venv .venv

$ mkdir ~/workspaces/myapp
$ cd ~/workspaces/myapp
$ cat <<EOF> demo.py
> with open('/Users/username/workspaces/myapp/demo.txt', 'a+') as f:
>     f.write('Hello, cron.\n')
> EOF

$ crontab -e

$ crontab -l
* * * * * /opt/myvenv/.venv/bin/python /Users/username/workspaces/myapp/demo.py  >> /Users/username/workspaces/myapp/demo.log 2>&1

$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x    5 username  staff   160B  6 20 09:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  136 username  staff   4.3K  6 20 09:18 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff     0B  6 20 09:23 demo.log
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   117B  6 20 09:23 demo.py
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    11B  6 20 09:24 demo.txt
```